# R data output weird formatting

Tags: r, gephi

I have a result of a function I wanna export from R to visualize it in Gephi.

The result is 79.552 pairs listed like this

```
[[79549]]
[1] 22 26

[[79550]]
[1] 41 26

[[79551]]
[1]34 26

[[79552]]
[1]25 26
```

I wan't the pairs to be exported so I have them like this in .csv

```
22, 26
41, 26
34, 26
25, 26
```

I'm using the `write.table` function like this, where `kj.csv` is my file and `kj` is my saved function.

```
write.table(kj, file = "kj.txt", append = FALSE, 
            quote = TRUE, sep = ",", eol = "\r\n",  
            na = "NA", dec = ".", row.names = TRUE, 
            col.names = TRUE, 
            qmethod = c("escape", "double"),fileEncoding = "")
```

A sample from my result .csv file looks like this (not the same numbers)

```
"c.22..26..483","c.41..26..596","c.34..26..543","c.25..26..773"
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list object. You could create a matrix and save it to file.  Here some sample data:

```
kj <- list(c(1,2), c(2,3))
```

Now create the matrix by treating each entry of the list as a row:

```
kj <- do.call(rbind, kj)
```

The matrix looks like this:

```
> kj                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
     [,1] [,2]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[1,]    1    2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[2,]    2    3
```

Save the matrix to file:

```
write.table(kj, "kj.txt")
```

The file `kj.txt` looks as follows:

```
"V1" "V2"
"1" 1 2
"2" 2 3
```

Comment: @MatiasBruhn if you think this answer solved your problem, feel free to mark it as the correct answer by checking off the grey check mark under the answer score.

Answer (score 3):

```
write.csv(t(as.data.frame(kj)), "kj.txt", row.names=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

You might possibly be interested by Rgexf, a library for R to create network files in the gexf format. This is a rich format that Gephi can read (it was actually created by the founders of Gephi).

Check: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgexf/index.html

And a comparison of the gexf format with other ones, such as csv:

https://gephi.org/users/supported-graph-formats/